# NodeJS Api framework recommendations including Graphql and ACL

Tags: node.js, acl, graphql, loopbackjs

I'm looking for some NodeJS framework/packages recommendations.
Little background: I used to write PHP code at a Novice to Pro level. Mainly using Laravel and CodeIgniter. I haven't touched PHP in 2 years due to job changes and focusing on other stuff.

Last half year I discover NodeJS and I'm loving it, its fast and the ability to create projects not only for the web but also for desktop applications and mobile devices all using the same language is such a Plus.

I'm currently working on a home automation tool for my new home but I'm struggling a bit because I can't find a proper easy to use framework (or combinations of packages) that have the following features. 
(This is only for the backend, for frondend I will be using angular 2,4,5 (what ever version angular 2 has now))

This are my current criteria:

- Easy API framework or easy way to implement models.
- Access control (ACL)
- Graphql

I tried Loopback framework and I really liked it.
It checks the API framework and ACL of my list, and as bonus works with almost every database you can image, but does not support Graphql.
I tried to add some extra packages (loopback-graphql-server, loopback-graphql and loopback-graphql-checkacl) but unfortunately I was not able to make them work properly, ether the ACL did not work properly or it did not work at all. (I spend several hours debugging loopback-graphql-server to find out why I got an access denied message in graphql when it was working perfectly using the rest api)

So I'm looking for some framework or combination of packages where this works quite out of the box.
Any recommendations would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow SailJS which is like PHP Development architecture and you can manage it easily

Other hand you can make your own framework using express just you need to know how javascript design pattern work

In my suggestion, You can use SailJS
 [Sail JS Web Site](https://sailsjs.com)

Answer (score 0):

I remember [DHH](http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/) writing about having choosing a "[single layer of cleverness](http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/arc/2005_09.html)". He was making the point that while database were capable of making decisions about what data was acceptable and what wasn't, that was fundamentally logic that belonged in the application layer and should just live in that one place.

I think GraphQL is an opportunity to think those boundaries through again.

What additional value does your db schema bring when when it's sitting behind a more powerful GraphQL schema (more powerful by virtue of being able to apply across every system behind it)?
What value is model based validation bringing over what's possible with custom types?
What value is the abstraction of a "model" once you remove behaviour like validation from it?

It sounds like most of the application will be Angular on the frontend and the backend you envision as a place to get data from. In that situation adding a framework increases the amount of code in your system, ups the learning requirements and doesn't (IMO) provide a clear value add once placed behind GraphQL.

Your schema fields and resolvers essentially replace what would have been controllers (in a Rails-like MVC app), some combination of types & custom types handle validation, auth is handled by an `Authorization` header (created on the frontend perhaps by [Auth0](https://auth0.com/)) and either a [Higher Order Component or maybe some directives](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs#databasequery). All that's missing would be some functions that fetch the data.

Most of my data fetching functions are wrapping and exporting something like this (this is [example code taken from Arango-js](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs#databasequery)):

```
const cursor = await db.query(aql`
  FOR u IN _users
  FILTER u.authData.active == ${active}
  RETURN u.user
`);
```

It's just a function, clean, simple & readable. No models, and no ORMs required.

What I am getting at here is that GraphQL gives most (maybe all?) of the structure we used to rely on a framework to provide. Essentially GraphQL is the framework. That, some resolvers and a fistful of other functions is probably all you need. There are situations where having a framework behind GraphQL makes sense, but do some thinking about whether yours is one of them.